# Tryiing to redirect http to https ins apache2

Tags: apache, ssl, https, debian, owncloud

I followed [this](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2013/04/how-to-setup-owncloud-server-5-with-ssl-connection.html) tutorial on how to create owncloud on my server using SSL.  The problem I'm having is that I would like to redirect any http requests to https.  I'm know that my Document root for http is located in /var/www but not sure where the https one is located.  I'm assuming that I have to edit or create a virtual host config that redirects to https. I do not know exactly where to create this configuration setting. In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-defualt ?

I also found you can do this using mod-rewrite but I cannot seem to find my
htaccess or httpd.conf files.   Is this because I installed apache using Debian?

Answer (score 1):

You can put this inside of the 000-default file you have and it will redirect you to the secure version of your site.  Replace example.com with your domain name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RedirectPermanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

It looks like you already have a virtual host for SSL from the tutorial so this should be all you need.  Hope this helps.